# Meaning of the bold blue font in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing

I am new to programming and Java. I am trying to learn it by doing. I am studying the open source library where I found 1 unit test. I created a "sandbox", where I copied this unit test and I try to put all the code into the main method.

I have the following question: why does the double and int type of variables have **blue bold font** in the unit test and they are brown in my sandbox. Does that mean that these variables changed somehow? If yes, how did they change ( Should I worry about different behavior of the code than in Unit tests?)
For example,

The original screenshot of the test file:

[image: original]

Screenshot of my file:

[image: my_file]

and see how I played with Eclipse IDE suggestion to remove the warnings:

[image: Eclipse suggestion]

It is written that Name `'TOLERANCE_ROOT' and 'STEP_MAX' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'`. I believe that it is problem with conventions that my types of the variables in main method are different from the same types of variables in the test class.

Comment: bold blue means it's an effective constant variable. Means, it is an `static final` variable like described here: [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) Please keep in mind that - while it is java related - your question points to specific behavior of 3rd party software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue bold font is because of the Java syntax coloring of `static final` fields: in ***Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring***, in *Element* select ***Java > Static final fields***.

The message `'TOLERANCE_ROOT' and 'STEP_MAX' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'` does not come from the Eclipse Java development tools (JDT), but from a plug-in such as [Checkstyle](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/checkstyle-plug) which has been installed separately to check Java naming conventions.

The naming conventions for final static fields (constants) is to use capital letters, in contrast to all others field which should be in camel case and begin with a lower case letter: `double TOLERANCE_ROOT` and `int STEP_MAX` should be `static final` (or renamed to `double toleranceRoot` and `int stepMax`).